# Bot Framework An Operation Was Attempted on Something That is Not a Socket

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-language-understanding

After deploying a bot on Microsoft Teams for multiple users to test, I have begun getting the above error. This has occurred in two different places. I'll post the stack traces for each:
https://gist.github.com/MilesWilde/49f290a9ba6f5e0b970de76b1907bb10

The line that this is occurring on (270 of `Bot.cs`) looks like this

```
var recognizerResult = await _services.LuisServices[DispatchKey].RecognizeAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
```

The second instance of this occurring has this stack trace:
https://gist.github.com/MilesWilde/ba68c336a3687e1a2b5d5611a7a854a6

And on line 391 of `SomeDialog.cs` is:

```
await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("Alright.");
```

Which seems really weird because we successfully send activity messages a lot. Is there any information available about why this would start occurring with a bot once more users are accessing the bot? This hasn't happened yet when my team tests it with our deployed development version.

Note: I am using the bot framework SDK v4

Comment: I've never seen this error before.  How many concurrent users?  Is the bot hosted on Azure?  How often does the exception occur?

Comment: We have about 10 people testing it however maximum 3 were using it when this error occurred. Only two people got the error though. The bot is hosted on Azure. This only started happening recently however it occurred about 5 times in an hour. They stopped testing it so it hasn't happened since but it seemed to be fairly random.

Comment: Do you have Application Insights configured for the bot and the web application hosting the bot?

Comment: Bot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-analytics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#enable-analytics
Web Application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, we haven't set up Application Insights yet. I'm assuming right now, but is this to figure out how much traffic is occurring? I feel like this error is happening even when only one person is using the bot. We'll set it up anyway. What information should I report back to you?

Comment: It would be good to have a stack trace.  I've never seen the "An Operation Was Attempted on Something That is Not a Socket" error from calling LUIS.

Comment: Alright, we'll keep monitoring and post back when this error occurs again

Comment: This error occurred again. What kind of information should we look at within Application Insights?

Comment: Anything that provides more information around why this exception occurred.